# No funciona un menú toggle en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con un menú toggle y no se que pasa. Si me podéis echar un cable os agradecería.

Resulta que tento este condicional donde solo funciona el IF, pero la condición del Else no se ejecuta.

Código HTML:

```
 <div class="hablemos_fixed" id="hablemos_container"><a href="mailto:contacto@rafaelgerardo.com">contacto@rafaelgerardo.com</a></div>
<img class="icono_hablamos" id="hablamos_svg" src="./icons/Hablemos.svg" alt="mensaje_svg">
```

Código Javscript:

```
    const hablemos_svg = document.getElementById("hablamos_svg");
    const hablemos = document.getElementById("hablemos_container");


    hablemos_svg.addEventListener("click", function() {

    hablemos.classList.toggle("hablemos_fixed_active");

    if (hablemos_svg.src = "./icons/Hablemos.svg") {
        hablemos_svg.src = "./icons/cerrar.svg";
    } else {
        hablemos_svg.src = "./icons/Hablemos.svg";
    }
    });
```

La línea de código del "IF" si se ejecuta, o sea sí cambia el SRC de la imagen, pero cuando le voy a volver a dar a ese "boton" para que cambie el SRC, o sea se ejecte la condicion del "ELSE", no lo hace.

Se trata de un simple menú que se activa y desactiva, el toggle muestra y oculta el DIV del menú. Todo funciona menos el "ELSE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el `if` **no estás comparando, sino asignando**, porque sólo has puesto un carácter `=`. Entonces el resultado es que asignas el icono Hablemos, y el `if` lo que evalúa es el valor asignado, que al ser una cadena es considerado true, y nunca te entra en el `else`.

Tienes que poner `==`:

```
if (hablemos_svg.src == "./icons/Hablemos.svg") {
```

Pero con eso solucionado aparece otro problema, y es que siempre se entra en el `else`, osea, nunca da por bueno que el `src` del icono sea `./icons/Hablemos.svg`.

Esto es porque `hablemos_svg.src` **te da la ruta completa, no la relativa**, puedes comprobarlo haciendo `alert(hablemos_svg.src);'

Entonces una solución es mirar si el `src` termina con el icono que queremos comparar, usando la función `endsWidth`:

```
if (hablemos_svg.src.endsWith("/icons/Hablemos.svg")) {
```

Ojo, date cuenta de que he quitado el `.` por el que empezaba la ruta del icono, porque eso no estará en la ruta completa. Incluso para simplificar podrías poner solamente `Hablemos.svg`.

He replicado el script, lo he probado y va perfecto.

Comment: A pesar de hacer eso no funciona. Incluso, si le agrego el == deja de funcionar todo el condicional. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Eso es un error que está claro. Quizá tengas más. Proporciona más datos, consulta la consola del navegador a ver si aparecen errores Javascript.

Comment: No aparecen errores. Y cuando hago  Click en el elemento la ruta en el SRC se resalta pero sigue manteniendo la ruta del condiciona IF, no cambia a ELSE. Y la ruta que está activa en ese momento es "./icons/cerrar.svg"; o sea, se deberia ejecutar el ELSE por que no se cumple el IF. Está que me explota la cabeza con este error. Gracias por responder!!

Comment: Ya lo solucioné. Solo el valor de SRC lo metí en una variable y lo fui sobreescribiendo con cada ejecución. Graciaspor tu interés! Buen día!

Comment: Ok, yo he editado la respuesta para explicarte por qué fallaba.

Comment: No olvides marcarla como correcta @rafaelgerardo si te ha ayudado.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho! Muchas gracias por vuestras respuesta! Ya la he marcado como respuesta válida!

Comment: También he modificado el código a tu modo @JoséCarlosPHP . Mucho más limpio que mi solución! Gracias!